# Office UI Outlook addin using auth is unstable

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office-js, azure-ad-msal

We're currently developing a Office UI addin using React. The addin should make a connection with a backend api and authenticate the user using bearer tokens. The backend api is protected by Azure AD.

We based our solution on the example that is offered by Microsoft: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React This uses msal.js for the authentication.

The login dialog is opened like so:

```js
await Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogLoginUrl, { height: 40, width: 30 }, result => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        displayError(`${result.error.code} ${result.error.message}`);
      } else {
        loginDialog = result.value;
        loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processLoginMessage);
        loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, processLoginDialogEvent);
      }
    });
```

And the following code runs within the dialog:

```js
import { UserAgentApplication } from "msal";
(() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = () => {
    const config = {
      auth: {
        clientId: "",
        authority: "",
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/login.html",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
      }
    };

    const userAgentApp = new UserAgentApplication(config);

    const authCallback = (error, response) => {
      if (!error) {
        if (response.tokenType === "id_token") {
          localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "yes");
        } else {
          // The tokenType is access_token, so send success message and token.
          Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "success", result: response.accessToken }));
        }
      } else {
        const errorData = `errorCode: ${error.errorCode}
                                   message: ${error.errorMessage}
                                   errorStack: ${error.stack}`;
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "failure", result: errorData }));
      }
    };

    userAgentApp.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback);
    const request = {
      scopes: ["api://..."]
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "yes") {
      userAgentApp.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
    } else {
      // This will login the user and then the (response.tokenType === "id_token")
      // path in authCallback below will run, which sets localStorage.loggedIn to "yes"
      // and then the dialog is redirected back to this script, so the
      // acquireTokenRedirect above runs.
      userAgentApp.loginRedirect(request);
    }
  };
})();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem lead to a stable addin. The authentication dialog sometimes works as expected, but sometimes it doesn't. In Outlook on macOS it seems to work fine, but in Outlook on Windows the handling of the callback is not always working correctly. Also in the web version of Outlook it doesn't work as expected.

The question is whether someone has a working solution using React and msal.js in a Outlook addin.

Comment: replaced outlook-addin tag with outlook-web-addins

Comment: Msal.js is kind of funky in how it handles Local Storage. Try deleting all of the Local Storage for your add-in's domain.

Comment: You can also try opening an issue in the MSAL repro here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT There already is a issue over there that about the usage of msal.js in a Outlook addin. Unfortunately there was no reply from Microsoft.
See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1072

Comment: This issue is fixed by MSAL team- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/1667. WIth latest release user should be unblocked.

Comment: Hi @Saab, were you able to solve this issue? My solution, which is not working for all scenarios, is using the UserAgentApplication.loginPopup and overriding the private method UserAgentApplication.openPopup to open an Office dialog in the Outlook for Windows and Mac.